# Saving NetCDF as subsets of the time dimension using xarray

Tags: netcdf, python-xarray

I have a NetCDF with one variable (front) and four dimensions (time, altitude, lat and lon). Downloaded from https://coastwatch.pfeg.noaa.gov/erddap/griddap/erdGAtfnt10day_LonPM180.html

It is a monthly composite, i.e. <xarray.DataArray 'time' (time: 151)>
array(['2001-01-16T12:00:00.000000000', '2001-02-16T00:00:00.000000000', ...'2013-12-16T12:00:00.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]').

I would like to create a single file (either a NetCDF or Geotif it doesn't matter which) for each timestamp.

I've tried:

```
ds = xr.open_dataset("Front_monthly2001to2013.nc", decode_times=True)

months, datasets = zip(*ds.groupby("time.month"))  #.groupby("time.month")
paths = ["test%s.nc" % m for m in months]
xr.save_mfdataset(datasets, paths)
```

But then it groups all the months and I get 12 output files instead of one for each year-month.
How do I save by year-month (which is the same, in my case, as each timestamp)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [datetime components](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/time-series.html#datetime-components) of your time dimension to re-format the timestamp to year & month and use it for grouping:

```py
months, datasets = zip(*ds.groupby(ds.time.dt.strftime("%Y%m")))
```